# incorrect position when drawing over canvas - HTML & JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I have a picture in a drawing canvas and im setting it as showing below in the code:

```
<div class="two40">
   <img class = "hidden" src="lungs.PNG"width="100%" height="300" id="lungs">
   <canvas height="300px" style="background:transparent; width: 100%; height: 300" id="specialLung"></canvas>
 </div>


function draw(){                
     var drawing = document.getElementById("specialLung");
     var con = drawing.getContext("2d");
     var image = document.getElementById("lungs");
     con.drawImage(image, 0, 0, drawing.offsetWidth, 300);

 }
```

the goal in here is to draw a circle in the position of the mouse click. the problem im facing is that the circle is drawn in a different position than the mouse clicking position it has an offset to the top left.

the canvas if placed under a div.
with the following structure

```
<div>
  <div> 
     !!some code    
  <div>
  <div>
     !!Canvas and picture code
  </div>
<div>
```

So, what might the problem be? what im missing!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To start, you're using invalid values for the css `height` of the canvas, that `300` should be `300px`.

Even then, you're stretching the canvas with css, which isn't adding pixels to the canvas buffer. You can test this by drawing a square on the canvas using `ctx.fillRect( 10, 10, 30, 30 )`: you will see that it will in fact be a rectangle. You need to do something to counteract this.

I'm going to assume you didn't mean to scale the canvas with css and want your squares to be squares. In that case, what you know is that you want the width of the canvas to be the same as the width of the parent, so you can literally do that:

`parentElement.addEventListener( 'resize', function(){ canvas.width = parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width } );`

At this point, your canvas will have the full width of the parent with the correct pixel aspect ratio, but an issue that will arise is that the contents of your canvas will be redrawn, as changing the `width` and `height` of the canvas through the javascript element's variable will result in a reset of the drawing buffer. You don't need to worry about what this means too much, but you still need to find a way to keep those contents, if that's what you're aiming for.

A fairly sensible solution is to create a virtual canvas

```
var virtualCanvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' ),
    virtualCtx = virtualCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
virtualCanvas.height = canvas.height; // or 300
```

then before changing `canvas.width` in the resize event listener, you set the width of the `virtualCanvas` to the width of the canvas before resizing, and simply draw the current canvas on the virtual one to store it, with `virtualCtx.drawImage( canvas, 0, 0 );`. You won't encounter issues with alpha channels, most likely, as changing the width of the `virtualCanvas` will also remove everything within it.

At this point, all you need to do is readd the drawings of the `virtualCanvas` to the `canvas` with `ctx.drawImage( virtualCanvas, 0, 0 );`, and you're golden!